How to refresh the facebook page access token
Page access token expires periodically and if it expires, I need to generate a new one manually.
Is it possible if the page access token can be refresh via code?
Here's my code in react typescript:
const PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN = "EAAcAHP";
const PAGE_ID = "123456";


export const fetchPageFeed = async () => {
  try {
    // Fetch page profile picture
    const pageInfoResponse = await axios.get(
      `https://graph.facebook.com/${PAGE_ID}`,
      {
        params: {
          access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN,
          fields: "picture{url},name,link", 
        },
      }
    );

    // Fetch page posts
    const postsResponse = await axios.get(
      `https://graph.facebook.com/${PAGE_ID}/posts`,
      {
        params: {
          access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN,
          fields:
            "id,message,created_time,picture,full_picture,attachments{media_type,media},reactions.summary(total_count),comments.summary(total_count),shares,video_tags,videos{source,description,thumbnails}",
        },
      }
    );

    return {
      profilePictureUrl: pageInfoResponse.data.picture.data.url,
      pageName: pageInfoResponse.data.name,
      pageUrl: pageInfoResponse.data.link, 
      posts: postsResponse.data.data,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching page feed:", error);
    return { profilePictureUrl: "", pageName: "", pageUrl: "", posts: [] }; 
  }
};



I use this code for a company public website where it shows to any website visitors their facebook page feeds.
